# Under what scenarios would one want to connect to a host other than localhost?

Tags: mysql

Under what scenarios would one want to connect to a host other than localhost? What I mean is when:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
```

I provide 'localhost' as the first argument without ever stopping to think what purpose it serves. I guess the opposite would be remote host, but when would you actually use it?

Comment: Sorry, did not think it was an open question, if a question was closed, should I delete it?

Comment: You could delete closed questions, but this one is not too bad: no downvotes, two votes to reopen. some votes on the answers, no obvious duplicate. I'd leave it around.

Comment: @Thilo You are right, I guess it wont kill anyone :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localhost` is a hostname that refers to the local machine.

Therefore, you pass that to connect to a server running on the local machine.

If you want to connect to a MySQL server running on a different machine, you would pass that machine's domain name or IP address instead of `localhost`
.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the SQL server is living. In an application architecture you could potentially have UI, Services, and SQL living on separate boxes. In this scenario you'd point mysql_connect() to the appropriate machine.

Answer (score 1):

localhost is simply an alias for the computer that you are running the script on. By connecting to localhost, you are connecting to a server on the same computer.

Replacing 'localhost' with an IP or host name allows you to connect to a different computer.